Missing data in nested interface after mapping
I am retrieving data using HttpClient in angular. I prepared an interface to map the json response, which has nested objects. In one nested array the values are missing.
Component:
export class PlansDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  exerciseForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({})
  planId? : number;
  plan? : Plan;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private http: HttpClient, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      this.planId = Number(params.get('id'));
    });
    this.http.get<GetPlanQueryResult>('https://localhost:7186/plans/'+this.planId).subscribe({
      next: response => {
        this.plan = response.plan
        console.log(this.plan.exercises[0].records);
        this.initializeForm();
      },
      error: (err) => {
        console.error(err);
      }
    })
  }

Interfaces prepared to map data:
import {Plan} from "./plan";

export interface GetPlanQueryResult {
  plan: Plan;
}

import {Exercise} from "./exercise";

export interface Plan {
  id: number;
  archived: boolean;
  name: string;
  exercises: Exercise[];
}

import {Record} from "./record";

export interface Exercise {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  records: Record[];
}

export interface Record {
  weight: number;
  repetitions: number;
  date : string;
}

Example Json response from postman:
{
    "plan": {
        "id": 1023,
        "archived": false,
        "name": "testssss",
        "exercises": [
            {
                "id": 1044,
                "name": "klata",
                "description": "",
                "records": [
                    {
                        "weight": 2,
                        "repetitions": 0,
                        "date": "2024-07-09T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "weight": 2,
                        "repetitions": 0,
                        "date": "2024-07-09T00:00:00"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 1045,
                "name": "klata",
                "description": "",
                "records": [
                    {
                        "weight": 3,
                        "repetitions": 0,
                        "date": "2024-07-09T00:00:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "weight": 3,
                        "repetitions": 0,
                        "date": "2024-07-09T00:00:00"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

As you can see API returns records, but after mapping records array are empty


Record is a typescript utility type. Even if you import your own Record interface, the utility type might be preferred.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type
Try to rename your Record interface
